# need to pass parameter from controller to .html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller code:

```
def description  
   product = @products.find(params(:id))  
end
```

This is in the controller and I have to pass the product variable to `description.html.erb`. How can I do this?

It is giving me an `ArgumentError` in `StoreController#description`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the way variables from the controller get passed to the views is by assigning them as an instance variable, which are variables defined with an `@` before it, e.g `@products`. If you want the `product` variable to be passed along, it has to be set as `@product`, like so:

```
@product = @products.find ...
```

In this particular case, you are getting an error raised before your view even is called. The only line in your controller action is throwing this.

Make sure that `@products` is actually being set. It's not being set in the `#description` method, so is it being set in a `before_filter` here? Is `@products` able to call `#find`? In Rails we often only see a model calling this method, e.g `Product.find(params[:id])`.

Further more, I see that you're accessing your `params` hash with regular brackets instead of square brackets. In Ruby you use square brackets. This alone may be what's causing the error. Try changing that to:

```
@product = @products.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables from controller to views using `@`

example in controller :

```
@my_var = 'toto'
```

in view

```
<%= @my_var %>
```